# How to set up multiple one-to-one relationships in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, one-to-one, ef-core-3.0

I have two entities say `Parent`, and `Child`; each parent can have at most two child references. I have set up my entities as follows:

```cs
class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public int PrimaryChildId{ get; set; }
    public Child PrimaryChild { get; set; }

    public int SecondaryChildId { get; set; }
    public Child? SecondaryChild { get; set; }
    // remaining properties
}

class Child 
{
    [Key]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent {get; set; }

    // remaining child properties 
}
```

In the `DbContext.OnModelCreating` I have this code:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>(builder =>
    {
        builder.HasOne(p => p.PrimaryChild);
        builder.HasOne(p => p.SecondaryChild);
    });
}
```

This isn't enough to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve here. I get an error:

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Child.Parent' of type 'Parent'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

I've tried to set up the relationship from the `Child` entity, but I get different errors because this makes me set up two relationships for the same property. I don't want to have two navigation properties on my child when I know only one will be used at a time as it would make for a confusing model.

I've searched the internet a bit, but I'm not having any luck finding relationships that are set up in this manner.

Comment: I think it is better to use one to many. Because you have one parent and many children. To make it one to one is not good theoreticaly

Comment: How would EF know which child is primary and which is secondary?  I think you have a many-to-one relationship here.  You can enforce your own rules in the domain logic.  You can create your own `PrimaryChild` property to get the first child in the collection or something similar.

Comment: @Anton, yes, that's what I'm starting to think.  I could always enforce the restriction in the business layer, and then this will actually make it easier in the future if the requirements change.  I am kind of curious if this is possible though, so I think I'll leave the question active.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Agreed @chadnt.  I was only thinking about the business requirement when I designed this, and if I was doing all of the database management manually this certainly could be done, but I don't think it's worth giving up the power of the ORM for this.

Comment: But you can try to remove Parent and Parent Id from child and not to use modelbuilder. Possibly, EF core will create two one-to-one manually.

Comment: @Anton, that seems to be giving a cascading delete error.  I'm not sure if that's due to another issue, or these relationships.  I think it's best to go with your initial suggestion.  This isn't worth the effort for an unnecessarily (outside of business requirements) more restrictive database.  It will be more easy to enforce the rule on the business layer.

Comment: @Jesse good. I jusr made a brainstorm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying something like this for the last few days, and after trying all sorts of Data Annotations and Fluent API nonsense, the cleanest solution I could come up with turned out to be very simple which requires neither. It only requires adding a 'private' constructor to the Parent class (or a 'protected' one if you're using Lazy Loading) into which your 'DbContext' object is injected. Just set up your 'Parent' and 'Child' classes as a normal one-to-many relationship, and with your database context now available from within the 'Parent' entity, you can make 'PrimaryChild' and 'SecondaryChild' simply return a query from the database using the Find() method. The Find() method also makes use of caching, so if you call the getter more than once, it will only make one trip to the database.

Here is the documentation on this ability: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#injecting-services

Note: the 'PrimaryChild' and 'SecondaryChild' properties are read-only. To modify them, set the 'PrimaryChildId' and 'SecondaryChildId' properties.

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent() { }
    private MyDbContext Context { get; set; }
    // make the following constructor 'protected' if you're using Lazy Loading
    private Parent(MyDbContext Context) { this.Context = Context; }

    [Key]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryChildId { get; set; }
    public Child PrimaryChild { get { return Context.Children.Find(PrimaryChildId); } }
    public int? SecondaryChildId { get; set; }
    public Child SecondaryChild { get { return Context.Children.Find(SecondaryChildId); } }
    // remaining properties
}

class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
    // remaining child properties 
}
```

Comment: My reqs have since changed and I don't even have this setup anymore, but that's a pretty slick solution.  Accepted the answer, because that definitely would've worked for me.